# Find an element in a nested list? (scheme)

Tags: list, scheme

I am trying to write a very simple procedure that checks to see if an arbitrary value is an element of a nested list. For example,, if the list is this
`(8 (4 (3 () ()) (2 () ())) (5 (13 () ()) (28 () ()))))`, and we were to check if the number `6` is a part of that list and return #f if it isn't, and #t if it is, how would we do so? We cannot simply cdr down the list because we would only retrieve the next list, and not the elements inside the next list. I was maybe thinking to use filter, but am not sure if that is the best direction for the procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work

```
  (define (find-elem l e)
    (cond [(empty? l) #f]
          [(equal? (first l) e) #t]
          [(list? (first l)) (or (find-elem (first l) e) (find-elem (rest l)e))]
          [else (find-elem (rest l) e)]))
```

If you are used to `car` and `cdr` than you have replace `first` by `car` and `rest` by `cdr`.

Comment: Ok, I checked the code and it did work. However, I do not understand what is happening in the 4th line of code, could you perhaps explain what is happening? from what I understand, that statement is checking whether the car is a list, and if it is, then return `(or (find-elem (first l) e) (find-elem (rest l)e))` . Is it returning that `or` statement? I don't quite understand

Comment: If the first element of the list l is a list we recurse on it. But we also recurse on the the rest of the list l. If in either one we find the element we are good to go. Therefore we use an OR. Either we find the element in the first element of l (a list) OR in the rest of l.

Comment: ok, I understand that now! Thank you for the concise explanation

Answer (score 0):

The other answer looks like `#!racket` code and will only work on proper lists. This is written in the latest R7RS Scheme version and should work an all list structure. To make it work in R6RS just replace the two first lines with the comment.

```
#!r7rs ; #!r6rs
(import (scheme base)) ; (import (rnrs base))

(define (needle-exists? needle haystack)
  (or (equal? needle haystack) ; does this node remsemble this part of the haystack 
      (and (pair? haystack)    ; if not require pair and do car, then cdr if not found.
           (or (needle-exists? needle (car haystack)) 
               (needle-exists? needle (cdr haystack))))))

(define tree '((a b) (c . d) (e (d e a d)) . g))    

(needle-exists? '(a) tree)   ; ==> #f
(needle-exists? '(b) tree)   ; ==> #t
(needle-exists? '(a d) tree) ; ==> #t
(needle-exists? 'g tree)     ; ==> #t
```